# "It is worth informing you that..." OR

Tags: expressions

How should I convey the following concept as a native in a business letter:

> - Also, it is worth informing you that...
> - Also, it is worth telling you that...
> - Also, it is worthy to inform you that...
> - Also, it is worthy to tell you that...

In case my suggestions do not sound idiomatic / natural for you, I am wide open to hear other suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ***worth pointing out*** that this is by far the most common expression in most contexts.

But it's a bit informal, so it's also ***worth noting*** that this one is more appropriate in some formal contexts.

---

OP's versions with *worthy* are completely unnatural (in fact, "worthy" is probably a word you never really want to use - it's usually somewhat dated, formal, and/or used facetiously).

And depending on context, it might be a bit "presumptive" to explicitly mention the addressee ("you") in this way (if it's your boss at work, say). In *that* case, the question arises as to *in whose opinion* the information is important. You don't want to get bogged down in cumbersome/deferential phrasing like *"You may think it's worth me informing you that [blah blah]"*

Comment: It would appear we both had the same idea with it's worth pointing out so I guess that must be the best one!!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you very much for this comprehensive comment of yours. But one question arises here in mind! Does the word "nothing" have an implication of humility and politeness in this sense? In my language, using this word in this sense never ever works. Could you explain it a little more?

Comment: @A-friend: That's ***noting***, not ***nothing**!* Note that ***to note*** in this context means ***be aware of***, rather than ***make a written note of***.

Answer (score 1):

The first two are correct and could be used, although I'm not too sure about the last two. They sound slightly off although I cannot quite tell why. Some other (slightly more informal) suggestions could be

- Also worth noting is that..
- Please also note that...
- Also, worth pointing out is that...

These are the best three I could think to use, with the first two being slightly informal and relaxed.

Comment: Per my own answer, I think *"It's worth telling you that..."* (and indeed *informing*) are potentially presumptive, so they wouldn't be that common anywhere - particularly in *formal* contexts. But apart from that I'd say *pointing out* is relatively informal, whereas by avoiding explicit mention of both speaker and addressee, *noting* is a better fit in most formal contexts. Of course, in some formal contexts it's a bit cheeky to even mention anything like that - you either have to say it or you don't, and your assessment of value may not interest the addressee (who will decide for himself).

Answer (score 0):

"I should inform you that..."

but it's formal verging on hostile usage, here in the UK at least. It's the type of thing lawyers write if they're making a threat. "I should inform you that if you fail to respond to this letter within 28 days, an application for a court order will be made" - that kind of thing.

"Please note that ... "

is not as formal as "I should inform you", but it's still fairly formal.

Less formal still is just to get on and say the thing that you're about to say without prefacing it with an "I'm about to tell you something" statement. That's what I'd normally do in a business letter or email.

What tone are you trying to strike?